# On my vaio laptop wifi is on but not showing available networks

Tags: windows-8

I'm using windows 8 64-bit and i installed all drivers. When i turn on wifi, it will turn on but does not shows the available networks to connect. Kindly assist me to solve this problem.

Comment: can you please provide details like model no and name ? Also as johnny vegas has mentioned please include details like whether the switch is physical . And is the problem there as soon as you installed you win 8 or just recently. Please include as much details as possible. Our answers will not solve your problem otherwise

Answer (score 1):

this seems like a driver issue and is most likely caused by the fact that most drivers are made for windows 7 or older so they may be lacking some dependencies that windows 8 requires for its network management.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the hardware switch? Some sony laptops have a physical switch on the case somewhere (or a keyboard shortcut) which they say turns the wifi off, but all it actually does is turn the aerial off. What model laptop is it?